# block the refresh of the date when submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, date, events

I would like that at the time of the submission of the form, the date displayed below does not refresh during a next submission.

At the moment, if I put minutes or seconds, as soon as I enter a letter in the textarea or add a new note, the '{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}' of all notes refresh. And I would like to block the process

```html
class AddNote extends React.Component {




    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h3 className="NoteDetails">
                    {new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</h3>
                <span className="NoteLine"></span>
                    <div className="notes">
                        <p>{this.props.isTextDisplayed && this.props.text}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="reset"
                        className="deleteBtn"
                        onClick={() => this.props.handleDeleteNote(this.props.noteIndex)}
                    >
                        Supprimer
                    </button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNote;
```

```html
class Note extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { value: "", isTextDisplayed: false, notes: [] };
  
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleDeleteNote = this.handleDeleteNote.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }
  
    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ isTextDisplayed: true });
      this.setState(
        { notes: [ this.state.value,...this.state.notes,]},
        this.setState({ value: "" })
        
      );
    }
  
    handleDeleteNote(index) {
      this.setState({
        notes: this.state.notes.filter((_, itemIndex) => index !== itemIndex)
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="title">
            <h1>Notes</h1>
            <span className="LineTitle"></span>
          </div>
          
          
          <form id="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <textarea
              className="textNote"
              id="textZone"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              required
            ></textarea>

            <button type="submit" className="addBtn">
              Ajouter
            </button>
          </form>
  
          {this.state.notes.map((note, noteIndex) => (
            <AddNote
              key={noteIndex}
              text={note}
              isTextDisplayed={this.state.isTextDisplayed}
              noteIndex={noteIndex}
              handleDeleteNote={this.handleDeleteNote}
            />
          ))}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
  

export default Note;
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `event.preventDefault();` to your `handleChange` method?

Also, it's 2022, you really shouldn't be using class components ;)

Comment: Yees, it's same with event.preventDefault();

Comment: function is better ??

Comment: Yes definitely start to use functional components. They can do everything class components can do and more.

Comment: Do you want the date in `<h3 className="NoteDetails">` to remain fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

In React, when you are updating a state value, using its previous value, use the callback argument. This is due to the asynchronous nature of React updates.
(See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

In `handleDeleteNote`,

```
handleDeleteNote=(index)=>{ // arrow prevents the need to bind
    this.setState((state)=>({
        notes: state.notes.filter((_, itemIndex) => index !== itemIndex)
    }));
}
```

In `handleSubmit`,

```
handleSubmit=(event)=>{ // arrow prevents the need to bind
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState((state)=>({
        isTextDisplayed: true,
        notes: [state.value].concat(state.notes)
        value: ''
    }));
}
```

In case you want the date in `<h3 className="NoteDetails">` to remain fixed,
then, instead of re-rendering `{new Date().toLocaleDateString()` each time,
make it a state property.

```
this.state = {currentDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()};

<h3 className="NoteDetails">{this.state.currentDate}</h3>
```